# Black screen after logging in Ubuntu vm

Tags: virtualization

I dual-boot my laptop and use Windows 7 Pro primarily and have Ubuntu 13.10.

I've created a raw disk vmdk of the entire drive. I also use the latest VirtualBox. I would like to start Ubuntu in VirtualBox but have issues. It will boot to the log in screen. I log in, but the screen goes black. I have not been able to find a solution so far and hope someone might have an idea to try.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MadMike. I was able to jump start it with "sudo lightdm" from the recovery mode. I've not come across that link out of all the Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other answers to getting a [Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Instead of of creating an image from your drive, I would start with simply downloading the iso and running a fresh install from within VirtualBox and seeing if that works.

Comment: Thanks @John Reed. I followed a link on that page to [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html). Delaying the lightdm has worked. I haven't seen these answers in searches. Thanks again.